# how to get jhipster jwt private key?

Tags: java, jwt, jhipster

I am creating multiple microservice applications with jhipster. I am using UAA server for authentication and tasks related to users. I need to manipulate the JWT that jhipster creates and add a few properties to the payload, but I cannot seem to find how to get jhipster's private key.

jHipster is signing the jwt with rs256 algorithm. I have accessed the jwt and altered the payload, but I cannot sign it with the rs256 algorithm because I don't how to retrieve it. I tried to switch to symmetric algorithms but then I could not verify the token because the verifier works with rs256 algorithm.

```
ResponseEntity<OAuth2AccessToken> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(getTokenEndpoint(), entity, OAuth2AccessToken.class);
```

jhipster is using this code to authenticate and return a token.
I am trying to create a new token with:

```
JwtBuilder token = Jwts.builder()
            .setHeader(headerMap)
            .setClaims((Map<String, Object>) jwtMap.get("payload"))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privateKey);
        String newJwt = token.compact();
```

but I do not have the private key.

I tried to generate a new private key and work with it but I got `Caused by: org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.InvalidSignatureException: RSA Signature did not match content` error.
I want to change the jwt payload and add properties to it and use the new token as the access token for jhipster authentication.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the keystore generated using java keytool.

The command to use is described in comments of `application-prod.yml` in your generated uaa project.

```
keytool -genkey -alias uaa -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -keystore keystore.p12 -validity 3650
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I did what you said and I was able to create a private key. but I still get this error: `Caused by: org.springframework.security.jwt.crypto.sign.InvalidSignatureException: RSA Signature did not match content` and `org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidTokenException: Cannot convert access token to JSON`. I think I should change the public key as well, but I do not know how. can you help me? thanks in advance

Comment: sorry to comment again but I thought you should know that I get those errors when I try to use the generated JWT in other parts of the system, not during the creation of the JWT. thanks